# Passing cause string to remote trigger Jenkins URL is not working

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-api

i'm triggering a job with the following command:

```
curl http://username:usertoken@localhost:8080/job/Test/build?token=test123&cause=This+was+started+by+testuser
```

The job is successfully triggered, but the cause message is not displayed.

Comment: Can you some more information? Which Jenkins version do you use? Where do you look for the cause message? I ask, because I just tried it out and I am getting the message like this `Started by remote host 192.168.0.29 with note: Hey hey hey`

Comment: I'm using Jenkins 2.32.1. I also wanted to display it after the "Started by remote host" message. Did you only use the curl command without POST?

Answer (score 1):

First, it looks like you are triggering the build using GET (since it's the default option when not passing any method to curl). it is usually preferred to use POST for these types of requests. this is how I would do it:

```
curl -X POST --user "<USER>:<USER_TOKEN>" http://localhost:8080/job/<JOB_NAME>/build?token=mytoken&This+was+started+by+testuser
```

Now I suspect that the "cause" parameter is being ignored since you did not set the "Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)" option in the build configuration.

[See this example where I've set it to "mytoken"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2XuH.jpg)

Comment: When i use your command, i get the following error : "Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request"

Comment: This is probably since you're using Jenkins 2.0. You need to configure CSRF Protection or disable it (less recommended):  

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CSRF+Protection

Comment: I can confirm that the cause parameter is ignored if I use  '-u username:password' but it works fine using token and 'Trigger Builds Remotely".

Answer (score 1):

The problem here isn't jenkins, it's how the shell is interpreting the command. Since the url isn't quoted, when the shell sees the `&` in the url, it interprets that as an instruction to execute the command stated before it in the background, and everything after it is interpreted as a separate command. Since `cause=This+was+started+by+testuser` is a valid shell command to set the variable `cause` to `This+was+started+by+testuser`, this occurs and there is no further output, though `env` will show the new variable.

To avoid this, you can quote the url provided to curl:

```
curl 'http://username:usertoken@localhost:8080/job/Test/build?token=test123&cause=This+was+started+by+testuser'
```

or better yet, use arguments to curl:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/job/Test/build --user username:usertoken --data token=test123 --data cause='This was started by testuser'
```